# pass nullptr to variadic template pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I currently have the following functions:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> void Get(T* out, Args*... other);
template <typename T> void Get(T* out);
template <> void Get<int>(int* out);
template <> void Get<int64>(int64* out);
template <> void Get<double>(double* out);
template <> void Get<char*>(char** out);
template <> void Get<void*>(void** out);
```

called using:

```
Get(&i, &t, &f);
```

with having `i` as `int`, `t` as `char*` and `f` as `double`.

This works great with one exception, if I want to pass a null-pointer.

```
Get(&i, nullptr, nullptr, &t, &f);
```

gives

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:94:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘Get(int*, std::nullptr_t, std::nullptr_t, char**, float*)’
  Get(&i, nullptr, nullptr, &txt, &f);
                                       ^
main.cpp:94:39: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:18:46: note: template<class T, class ... Args> void Get(T*, Args* ...)
 template <typename T, typename... Args> void Get(T* out, Args*... other)
                                              ^
main.cpp:18:46: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:94:39: note:   mismatched types ‘Args*’ and ‘std::nullptr_t’
  Get(&i, nullptr, nullptr, &txt, &f);
                                       ^
main.cpp:28:28: note: template<class T> void Get(T*)
 template <typename T> void Get(T* out)
                            ^
main.cpp:28:28: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:94:39: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 5 provided
  Get(&i, nullptr, nullptr, &txt, &f);
                                       ^
```

How do I have to rewrite my `Get` functions to keep the old usage, except that they will accept a `nullptr` too?

Comment: What do the specializations do differently to the general T case?

Comment: The general T case gives an error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do something like:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::nullptr_t, T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type
Get(T out, Args... other);

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::nullptr_t, T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type
Get(T out);
```

So your specializations are different:

```
template <> void Get<int*>(int* out);
template <> void Get<int64*>(int64* out);
template <> void Get<double*>(double* out);
template <> void Get<char**>(char** out);
template <> void Get<void**>(void** out);
```

and potentially:

```
template <> void Get<nullptr_t>(nullptr_t); // the new one
```

BTW, you may prefer overloading (for `Get` with one argument): [Live example](https://ideone.com/IK7nUq).

Comment: Thanks! What does the enable_if do?

Comment: But wouldn't overloading `Get` prevent me from defining a general `template <typename T> void Get(T*)` case?

Comment: `enable_if<true, T>::type` is `T` (`void` is this case (default type)) whereas `enable_if<false,T>::type` doesn't exist and so discard the template thanks to SFINAE.

Comment: You can have the overload `void Get(int* out)` and `template <typename T> void Get(T*)`.

Comment: Did you maybe mean `Get(T out, Args... other)`? `Args*...` still complains about a type mismatch between `std::nullptr_t` and `Args*`. But when I change it to `Args...` I get a linker error when calling `Get` with a nullptr.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of overloading which may help you (you may still add the generic template method, but as it seems you use it only to report error, better to have compiler time error than runtime error).

Comment: Yes, I meant `Get(T out, Args... other)`

Answer (score 0):

First, some metaprogramming boilerplate.  This defines `enable_if_t`, `all_of`:

```
template<bool B, class T=void>
using enable_if_t=typename std::enable_if<B,T>::type;
namespace details {

  template <template<class>class test, class=void, class... Ts>
  struct all_of : std::true_type {};
  template <template<class>class test, class T0, class... Ts>
  struct all_of<test, enable_if_t< !test<T0>::value >, Ts... > : std::false_type {};
  template <template<class>class test, class T0, class... Ts>
  struct all_of<test, enable_if_t< test<T0>::value >, Ts... > : all_of<test, void, Ts...> {};
}
template<template<class>class test, class... Ts>
struct all_of : details::all_of<test, void, Ts...> {};
```

both of which are generally useful.  `enable_if_t` is a C++11 thing in `std`, if you have full support, just use `std::enable_if_t` instead.

Next, a trait that detects if something is a pointer or nullptr:

```
template<class X>
struct is_ptr : std::false_type {};
template<class X>
struct is_ptr<X*> : std::true_type {};
template<>
struct is_ptr<std::nullptr_t> : std::true_type {};
```

We then use that trait to provide SFINAE protection to our `Get` multi-arg method:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
enable_if_t<all_of<is_ptr, T, Args...>> Get(T const& out, Args const&... other);
```

Next, the interesting thing about function template specializations is "you aren't doing it" and "you shouldn't do it".  You are actually overloading `Get<T,Args...>`, you are just specializing `Get<T>`.  And there is little point if you are using deduction:

```
void Get( std::nullptr_t out );
void Get( int* out );
void Get( int64* out );
void Get( double* out );
void Get( char** out );
void Get( void** out );
```

put these single-arg versions of `Get` before your variardic body if the variardic body does recursion.

It is rarely a good idea to specialize template functions -- just override.